# How can I make this select lookup another table and find first match?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of phone call data from our phone system that I am trying to create a report on. These phone calls match up to a table of internal and external numbers. The report needs to try to match the phone call to an external number in our database first and if there is no match try to match it to an internal number.

I have created a sample data set and db-fiddle, and removed some data to hopefully explain it better:

```
CREATE TABLE `cdr` (
  `callnumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `origLegCallIdentifier` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateTimeOrigination` datetime NOT NULL,
  `callType` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `chargeable` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `callCharge` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `origNodeId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `destLegIdentifier` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `destNodeId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `callingPartyNumber` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `callingPartyNumberPartition` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `callingPartyNumberState` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `callingPartyNumberSite` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `originalCalledPartyNumber` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `originalCalledPartyNumberPartition` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `finalCalledPartyNumber` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `finalCalledPartyNumberPartition` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastRedirectDn` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastRedirectDnPartition` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dateTimeConnect` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateTimeDisconnect` datetime NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `origDeviceName` varchar(129) NOT NULL,
  `destDeviceName` varchar(129) NOT NULL,
  `origIpv4v6Addr` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `destIpv4v6Addr` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `cdr` (`callnumber`, `origLegCallIdentifier`, `dateTimeOrigination`, `callType`, `chargeable`, `callCharge`, `origNodeId`, `destLegIdentifier`, `destNodeId`, `callingPartyNumber`, `callingPartyNumberPartition`, `callingPartyNumberState`, `callingPartyNumberSite`, `originalCalledPartyNumber`, `originalCalledPartyNumberPartition`, `finalCalledPartyNumber`, `finalCalledPartyNumberPartition`, `lastRedirectDn`, `lastRedirectDnPartition`, `dateTimeConnect`, `dateTimeDisconnect`, `duration`, `origDeviceName`, `destDeviceName`, `origIpv4v6Addr`, `destIpv4v6Addr`) VALUES
(52004, 69637277, '2020-08-31 03:05:05', 'outbound-national', 'yes', '0.00', 4, 69637278, 4, '6220', 'PT_INTERNAL', 'NSW', 'Site A', '0412345678', 'PT_NATIONAL_TIME_RESTRICT', '0412345678', 'PT_NATIONAL_TIME_RESTRICT', '0412345678', 'PT_NATIONAL_TIME_RESTRICT', NULL, '2020-08-31 03:05:08', 0, 'SEP00XXXXX', 'XXXXX', '1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1');

CREATE TABLE `numbers` (
  `numberid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `memberid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('internal','external') NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `numbers` (`numberid`, `number`, `memberid`, `type`, `description`) VALUES
(1555, '0412345678', 436, 'internal', ''),
(1556, '6220', 437, 'external', '');
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ofH6sENoce8tGVsoxMejwZ/1

The above example shows how it ends up with a duplicate for a single record because it matches 6220 as the callingPartyNumber and 0412345678 as the finalCalledPartyNumber in each respective select.

This is an example of what I want to see (union has been removed):
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bVSWESvnKJKvuNefLqH4aU/0

I want a single record for when it either matches a finalCalledPartyNumber first or then a callingPartyNumber. Records that don't match anything will not be shown.

**Updated select using Caius's example**

```
SELECT
DATE(CONVERT_TZ(cdr.dateTimeOrigination,'+00:00',@@global.time_zone)) as 'Date',
TIME(CONVERT_TZ(cdr.dateTimeOrigination,'+00:00',@@global.time_zone)) as 'Time',
cdr.callType,
cdr.callingPartyNumberState, 
cdr.callingPartyNumber,
COALESCE(finalcalledparty.memberid, callingparty.memberid, originalcalledparty.memberid, 'No Match') as MemberID,
cdr.originalCalledPartyNumber,
cdr.finalCalledPartyNumber, 
CONCAT(MOD(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(cdr.duration)), 24), ':', LPAD(MINUTE(SEC_TO_TIME(cdr.duration)),2,0), ':', LPAD(second(SEC_TO_TIME(cdr.duration)),2,0)) as 'duration', 
cdr.callCharge 
FROM `cdr`
LEFT JOIN numbers finalcalledparty ON finalcalledparty.number = cdr.finalCalledPartyNumber
LEFT JOIN numbers callingparty ON callingparty.number = cdr.callingPartyNumber
LEFT JOIN numbers originalcalledparty ON originalcalledparty.number = cdr.OriginalCalledPartyNumber
WHERE (cdr.callType LIKE '%outbound%' OR cdr.callType LIKE '%transfer%' OR cdr.callType LIKE '%forward%')
ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC
```

**Select with members table join**

```
SELECT
DATE(CONVERT_TZ(cdr.dateTimeOrigination,'+00:00',@@global.time_zone)) as 'Date',
TIME(CONVERT_TZ(cdr.dateTimeOrigination,'+00:00',@@global.time_zone)) as 'Time',
cdr.callType,
'Calling' as ChargeType,
cdr.callingPartyNumberState, 
cdr.callingPartyNumber,
COALESCE(finalcalledmember.name, callingmember.name, 'No Match') as MemberName,
cdr.finalCalledPartyNumber, 
CONCAT(MOD(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(cdr.duration)), 24), ':', LPAD(MINUTE(SEC_TO_TIME(cdr.duration)),2,0), ':', LPAD(second(SEC_TO_TIME(cdr.duration)),2,0)) as 'duration', 
cdr.callCharge 
FROM `cdr`
LEFT JOIN numbers callingparty ON callingparty.number = cdr.callingPartyNumber
LEFT JOIN numbers finalcalledparty ON finalcalledparty.number = cdr.finalCalledPartyNumber
LEFT JOIN members callingmember ON callingmember.memberid = callingparty.memberid
LEFT JOIN members finalcalledmember ON finalcalledmember.memberid = finalcalledparty.memberid
WHERE (callType LIKE '%outbound%' OR callType LIKE '%transfer%' OR callType LIKE '%forward%') AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(cdr.dateTimeOrigination,'+00:00',@@global.time_zone)) = '2020-09-01'
ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic would make the question more easily understood.

Comment: Thanks, I have now updated it using db-fibble so everyone can hopefully make sense of it

Comment: The only thing I'd point out in response to your update is that you have associated m with c and m2 with f.. and you have coalesced such that f is first for memberid but m is first for membername (but m is associated with c, not f). I'd recommend you should have called them fm/cm or mf/mc because it's a bit more meaningful, rather than m and m2, and might have prevented this swapping mistake (if it is a mistake) being made. There are no prizes for shortest sql by the way; longer identifiers might make things more readable, like intnum/extnum/intmem/extmem?

Comment: Also, you should qualify the identifiers in theWHERE clause with an alias to show other humans who read this code where those columns live

Comment: @CaiusJard I have updated it again. It appears to be working better now. Do you have any recommendations on now joining the member table to get the member name from the member ID?

Comment: The current presentation of the query is a regression? Why have the members tables been removed from the query? They looked fine, just that you'd coalesced the name wrong, probably because m/m2 were poor choice of alias as noted

Comment: Note that I have added a paragraph to the bottom of my advice, dealing with a specific issue may encounter if your data contains nulls in the table rather than just a presenting nulls because of no match on the join

Comment: When you talk on SO, get into the habit of fully explaining your judgements of a solution - "it appears to be working better" is very vague and could blame an hundreds of things; better is a judgement that only exists in your head/based on criteria only you know. You need to fully explain those criteria and what concepts like "better" and "worse" mean in context

Comment: @CaiusJard Sorry should have mentioned I had removed it temporarily to simplify the select. What i'm noticing now is that when I add in the join for the members table to get the member name it goes from 247 records to 317. Any ideas why it would do this? Updated my post to include this select

Comment: Any time a join causes a record count to go up it means that a table on the left matches more than one row from a table on the right. Consider that if you did `select * from products` you might get 1000 rows of your shop sells a thousand products, but if you did `select * from products join orders on product.id = orders.productid` you might get 2000 rows if every product has been ordered twice; the orders table contains 2000 rows, it matches every product. If you want to see why your rows increase, comment all the selected columns out and put a `*` then look at the whole data

Comment: Note that I don't consider your `INNER JOIN members ON x OR y` to be the right thing to do and it is not the same as joining members in twice for different reasons like you had in your earlier iteration. By using OR in this way it will make your rowcount go up because you give it the opportunity to match multiple rows. Join it in twice or join in via a subquery or cte

Comment: Consider a Person table with a HomeAddressId and. WorkAddressId. `SELECT * FROM Person JOIN Address ha ON HomeAddressId = ha.id JOIN Address wa ON workAddressId = wa.id` will return one row per person with 3 columns (ignoring the IDs) - the person name, the home address and the work address. By contrast `Person JOIN Address a on WorkAddressId = a.id OR HomeAddressId = a.id` gives two rows per person of 2 columns; the name and the address, home on one row and work on the other. ie by doing an OR you've gone back to the first problem you caused by doing a union.See the bullet points in my answer

Comment: @CaiusJard I have updated the last select now with the members table join working correctly. I think I was over complicating it in my head. I'll just now need to validate that its giving me everything I'm expecting. I really appreciate you sticking with me and explaining everything. Thanks

Comment: Yes, though we've reverted to relatively meaningless m1 and m2 for c and t respectively. I really would recommend you use aliases of mc and mf (or cm and and cf) then you don't have to look/remember "is it m1 or m2 that is joined to c" - the "members table for C" knowledge is right there in the name "mC"

Comment: I just realised I copied the wrong one, fixed now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The report needs to try to match the phone call to an external number in our database first and if there is no match try to match it to an internal number.

You can use a pair of left joins for this. Here's a simpler dataset:

```
Person, Number
John, e1
James, i2
Jenny, x3

ExternalNumber, Message
e1, Hello

InternalNumber
i2, Goodbye


SELECT p.Person, COALESCE(e.Message, i.Message, 'No Match')
FROM
  Person p
  LEFT JOIN Externals e ON p.Number = e.ExternalNumber
  LEFT JOIN Internal e ON p.Number = i.InternalNumber
```

Results:

```
John, Hello
James, Goodbye
Jenny, No Match
```

Few things you need to appreciate about SQL in general:

- A UNION makes a dataset grow taller (more rows)
- A JOIN makes a dataset grow wider (more columns)
- It is easy to compare things on the same row, more difficult to compare things on different rows
- There isn't exactly a concept of "doing something now" and "doing something later" - i.e. your "try to match it to external first and if that doesn't work try match it to internal" isn't a good way to think about the problem, mentally. The SQL way would be to "match it to external and match it to internal, then preferentially pick the external match, then the internal match, then maybe no match"
- COALESCE takes a list of arguments and, working left to right, returns the first one that isn't null. Coupled with LEFT JOIN putting nulls when the match fails, it means we can use it to prefer external matches over internal

Because it's easier to compare things on the same row, we just try and match the data against the external and internal numbers tables as a direct operation. We use LEFT JOIN so that if the match doesn't work out, at least it doesn't cause the row to disappear..

So you join both numbers tables in and the matches either work out for external (and you will pick external), work out for internal but not external (and you will pick internal), work out for both int and ext (and you will pick ext over int), or don't work out (and you might have a message to say No Match)

---

It should be pointed out that the COALESCE approach only really works well if the data won't naturally contain nulls. If the data looked like this:

```
Person, Number
John, e1
James, i2
Jenny, x3

ExternalNumber, Message
e1, NULL

InternalNumber
i2, Goodbye
```

Then this will be the result:

```
John, Goodbye
James, Goodbye
Jenny, No Match
```

Even though the join succeeded, the presence of a NULL in the ExternalNumber.Message means the InternalNumber.Message is used instead, and this might not be correct. We can solve this by using CASE WHEN instead, to test for a column that definitely won't be null when a record matches:

```
CASE 
  WHEN e.ExternalNumber IS NOT NULL THEN e.Message 
  WHEN i.InternalNumber IS NOT NULL THEN i.Message
  ELSE 'No Match'
END
```

Because we test the column that is the key for the join the only way we can get a null there is when the join fails to find a match.

Comment: Thanks, greatly appreciate you explaining everything. I think I have got it right now, just need to validate that its getting everything I expected. I have updated the post with my current select based on your example